# How to keep track of the checked node id's in Kendo UI Treeview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treeview

I am using Kendo UI's treeview control with checkboxes in asp.net mvc. Both the parent and the child nodes have id properties. When the user checks on any child nodes I want to keep track of which ones have been checked. The following is my cshtml code along with the javascript code to keep track of the id's and my json used to populate the treeview.

```
                <div style="padding-top: 2em;">
                <h4>Status</h4>
                <p id="result">No nodes checked.</p>
            </div>

        <script>                   
            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true,
                },
                dataSource: {
                    //type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: '@Url.Content("~/Document/GetDocuments")',
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },                        
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "id", text: "Name",
                            children:  "Files"
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataTextField: [ "Name", "FileName"],
                check: onCheck                                 
            });
            // function that gathers IDs of checked nodes
            function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
                for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {                      
                    if (nodes[i].checked) {
                        checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].name);
                    }
                    if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                        checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
                    }
                }
            }
            // show checked node IDs on datasource change
            function onCheck() {                  
                var checkedNodes = [],
                    treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"),
                    message;
                checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
                if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {                        
                    message = "IDs of checked nodes: " + checkedNodes.join(",");
                } else {
                    message = "No nodes checked.";
                }
                $("#result").html(message);
            }
        </script>

json object
    [{"id":1,"Name":"Checking",
    "Files":[{"Filename":"doc10","id":"1afd5a4f-086f-44d2-9287-8098384e379e"},
    {"Filename":"doc11","id":"89ea3366-14b8-4e91-8273-6e2a51fbe516"}]},
    {"id":2,"Name":"Saving",
    "Files":[{"Filename":"doc20","id":"c7a88f5d-067e-4f20-93b6-da6eff69d532"},
    {"Filename":"doc21","id":"8a0a62ed-1b4a-4e5e-8d59-d57a975a7ab0"}]}]
```

When I check some of the child nodes it only display "IDs of checked nodes:,,,". So it looks like the ID value comes as blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

To get all selected Id's:-

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
    var data = [{ "id": 1, "Name": "Checking", "Files": [{ "Filename": "doc10", "id": "1afd5a4f-086f-44d2-9287-8098384e379e" }, { "Filename": "doc11", "id": "89ea3366-14b8-4e91-8273-6e2a51fbe516" }] }, { "id": 2, "Name": "Saving", "Files": [{ "Filename": "doc20", "id": "c7a88f5d-067e-4f20-93b6-da6eff69d532" }, { "Filename": "doc21", "id": "8a0a62ed-1b4a-4e5e-8d59-d57a975a7ab0" }] }];

    var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: data,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id", text: "Name",
                children: "Files"
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true,
            },
            dataSource: inline,
            dataTextField: ["Name", "Filename"],
            check: onCheck
        });
    });

    function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].checked) {
                checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
            }
            if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
            }
        }
    }

    function onCheck() {
        var checkedNodes = [],
            treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"),
            message;
        checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
        if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {
            message = "IDs of checked nodes: " + checkedNodes.join(",");
        } else {
            message = "No nodes checked.";
        }
        console.log(message);
    } 
</script>
```

To get all selected Name and Filename detail:-

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
    var data = [{ "id": 1, "Name": "Checking", "Files": [{ "Filename": "doc10", "id": "1afd5a4f-086f-44d2-9287-8098384e379e" }, { "Filename": "doc11", "id": "89ea3366-14b8-4e91-8273-6e2a51fbe516" }] }, { "id": 2, "Name": "Saving", "Files": [{ "Filename": "doc20", "id": "c7a88f5d-067e-4f20-93b6-da6eff69d532" }, { "Filename": "doc21", "id": "8a0a62ed-1b4a-4e5e-8d59-d57a975a7ab0" }] }];

    var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: data,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id", text: "Name",
                children: "Files"
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true,
            },
            dataSource: inline,
            dataTextField: ["Name", "Filename"],
            check: onCheck
        });
    });

    function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].checked) {
                if (nodes[i].Name)
                    checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].Name);
                else
                    checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].Filename);
            }
            if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
            }
        }
    }

    function onCheck() {
        var checkedNodes = [],
            treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"),
            message;
        checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
        if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {
            message = "IDs of checked nodes: " + checkedNodes.join(",");
        } else {
            message = "No nodes checked.";
        }
        console.log(message);
    }


</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It turns out that since I need the id from the children, I have to go one more level deep. So I have to use two for loops.